# '&' illegal operation on bound member function expression error

Tags: c++

Ok so here is my code:

```
#include "driver.h"
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Book.h"
#include "Author.h"
#include <vector>

void displayBooks(const vector<Book>& books)
{
    // students need to write the code for this function
    for (int i = 0; i < &books.size; i++)
    {
        std::cout << &books[i] << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{

    // create a vector for storing the account objects
    vector<Book> myBooks;

    // create three Author objects
    Author p1("J.K.Rowling", "Edinburgh, Scotland");
    Author p2("Suzanne Collins", "Connecticut, USA");
    Author p3("J.R.R. Tolkien", "Bournmouth, England");

    // Create three Book objects
    Book b1(p1, "Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone", 256, 24.95);
    Book b2(p2, "Mockingjay", 400, 12.99);
    Book b3(p3, "The Hobbit", 322, 14.29);

    // add the books to the vector
    myBooks.push_back(b1);
    myBooks.push_back(b2);
    myBooks.push_back(b3);

    // call the displayBooks function to display the books
    displayBooks(myBooks);
    cout << "\n\n";

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

The top part is what's causing me trouble, the displayBooks function. I keep getting an
'&' illegal operation on bound member function expression
error. How do I fix this?

Comment: `i < books.size()` And maybe `std::cout << books[i]`, assuming `Book` provides a suitable `operator<<` overload.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`&books.size` is not a valid expression.

`size` is a member function of `std::vector`. To call the member function, you need to use `books.size()`.

The presence of `&` in that expression leads the compiler to think that perhaps you are trying to get a pointer to the member function of the class, which can be obtained using `&std::vector<Book>::size`. However, you cannot get a pointer to a member function of the class using an object of the class. That is the translation of the message ***'&' illegal operation on bound member function error*** to plain English.

Comment: Ok I changed my function to                                                                             void displayBooks(const vector<Book>& books)
{
 for (unsigned int i = 0; i < books.size(); i++)
 {
  std::cout << books[i] << std::endl;
 }
}                                                                                                             and I'm getting these errors:

no operator "<<" matches these operands

Error C2679 binary '<<': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'const Book' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Comment: `std::cout << books[i]` will work only if you define a function `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, Book const& book);`.

Comment: Where am I supposed to put that?

Comment: @riahtron3000, declare the function in the same .h file where you define `Book`. Put the implementation in the same .cpp file where you implement the rest of the member functions of `Book`. If the function can be inlined, you can implement it in the .h file too.