# Class member function address

Tags: c++, class, directx

*Edit* How is this in any way related to the supposed post? They are both completely different errors, you guys should really stop trying to farm rep

So I've been searching around google and stackoverflow but I couldn't find one solution that would help my case.
I have a D3D9Device pointer and I want the EndScene address of that device, how would I approach so?

```
DWORD aEndScene = *(DWORD*)(&d3ddev->EndScene);
```

won't work with the following error

```
'&': illegal operation on bound member function expression
```

I think that's wrong because I'm actually trying to get the address of the d3ddev class

Comment: Looks like you need to us `*(DWORD*)(&(d3ddev->EndScene()))`

Comment: That won't work man like that I'm just calling the function

Comment: It's not clear whether you want the address of the return value of end scene, or you want something a bit like a function pointer except it can store a method and an object to call that method on. In the second case, you probably want to combine two concepts: use "std::function" as the type of variable / parameter you pass around, and use a "C++ lambda function" to create the value you put in that variable. Search the web for those two terms and you'll get most of the information you need.

Comment: @RSahu This is not a duplicate of that question.

Comment: I want to simply be aple to printf the EndScene address

Comment: @MatthewMackday, The compiler error message indicates that `EndSection` is a member function. The problem with what you are trying to do is two fold: 1) You cannot get the address of a member function using `&d3ddev->EndScene`. You'll have to use `&D3D9Device::EndScene`. 2) Printing the address of a member function is doable but not straight forward. Do a search on that topic in SO.

Comment: @MatthewMackday, when you use `d3ddev->EndScene`, you are not calling the function. You need to use `d3ddev->EndScene()` to call the function.

Comment: @MatthewMackday, the comment *you guys should really stop trying to farm rep* is uncalled for. We are all volunteers here, trying our best to help others. A closed post can be reopened if necessary by others. I don't think the that would be the case here.

Comment: How is it uncalled for? You marked the post as a duplicate of a TOTALLY different post/situation and I don't think you've read the original one

Comment: @MatthewMackday noone gets any rep for closing a question. That comment should be in the comments, where it belongs. It does not belong in the body of the question.

Comment: @R Sahu: I agree that the comment about rep farming was inappropriate. However, I don't think this question is a duplicate of that other one (that one was an error where there was no "&" and there needed to be one; this one there is a "&" that is in appropriate). Voting to reopen...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Member function pointers are not per object, they are per type. In your example, you could have multiple instances of a `IDirect3DDevice9`, all of which would have the same pointer value for their `EndScene` member function (assuming they aren't different concrete types - but this isn't likely).

The specific error you are getting is because you are attempting to get the address of a pointer-to-member function from an object, which isn't valid (eg. see ['&' illegal operation on bound member function expression error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38288531/illegal-operation-on-bound-member-function-expression-error)).

It is possible to get the value of a member function using the type, instead of an object pointer. However, it's extremely ugly:

```
// Value is stored in 'end_scene':
HRESULT (IDirect3DDevice9::* end_scene)() = &IDirect3DDevice9::EndScene;
// Call the function, with the value of 'end_scene'.
(*d3ddev.*(end_scene))();
// Print the address of the pointer-to-member function:
printf("%p\n", end_scene);
```

I wouldn't suggest doing this here, because most functions in `IDirect3DDevice9` don't have the same prototype. In fact, only `BeginScene` has the same prototype as `EndScene`, and it's hard to imagine a situation in which the call could be one or the other, since they need to be called in a specific order. You could make the case about using this for the functions that get/set vertex/pixel shader constants, as they have the same prototypes, but, it's just as easy to store some other external state to determine which function to call, and much more straightforward.